# Adding integer elements to list JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to separate digits from an Integer and then put them into an array.

All elements, except for the first, are printing as 0. Could someone explain why this is it happening?

```
public class Doom{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int number = 1234;
        int[] list = new int[5];
        while (number > 0) {

            int x = 0;
            int fork = (number%10);
            System.out.println(fork);
            list[x] = fork;
            x++;
            number = number / 10;
        }
        for (int x : list){
            System.out.println(x);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem, aside from the best variable names, is that `int x = 0;` is inside your while loop. It keeps getting reset to 0 on every iteration.

Comment: `x = 0` is executed on every iteration…

Comment: lol thanks, i am feeling so stupid now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few errors in your program. Biggest one is that you are inializing x to 0 and then incrementing it by 1 within the while loop. It will keep storing your digits at the same location (0th place). Compare the following snippet and try to learn your mistakes:

```
public class Doom{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int number = 1234;
        int[] list = new int[String.valueOf(number).length()];
        int x = 0;
        while (number > 0) {        
            int fork = (number%10);
            System.out.println(fork);
            list[x] = fork;
            x++;
            number = number / 10;
        }
        for (int y : list){
            System.out.println(y);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It can be initialized to 0 too. But then you need to do `list[x] = fork`. Just updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: How can i use the length of the integer directly? i mean like something that would do int[] list = new int[number.length] , without errors ofcourse

Comment: @KillerHawx, you can get the length (number of digits) of 'number' by this way: `int length = String.valueOf(number).length();`

Comment: @KillerHawx, I just edited the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are declaring `x` *inside* the loop, so it gets reset to `0` each time. You want to move the `int x = 0;` line to be above the `while (number > 0) {` line, outside of the loop. Then it will be initialized to 0 only once, and each pass through the loop can assign it a new value with the `x++` line.

Answer (score 1):

You keep redeclaring x in your loop, causing only the first index to have meaningful data.  Move it to the outside of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are reinitializing x to 0 every time. Declare it outside of the while loop.